# Best method to detect the download capabilities of user, using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, download, connection, download-speed

I need to detect the download capabilities of the users device in order to figure out whether I should give them a large 50mb video to download or a small 40kb image to download.

My first thought was to detect the internet connection of the user (wifi/3G/LTE)  and then serve the file based on the result. However there is no clear way to do so unless using the extremely unreliable `navigator.connection`

Should I detect download speed or is there a better method. I want to know the most reliable method.

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya My question is asking the BEST method i should use to figure out which file should be given to user which CAN include speed detection. Your question deals exclusively with speed detection.

Comment: You can set condition..if internet speed is less than X then serve this file else another file

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya So you're saying that checking the internet speed is the best method to decide whether the user can handle downloading a bigger file. Is there a third option?

Comment: As per your question this is only a solution...-> check internet speed of user...

Comment: I can make an answer for this, or you can since you discovered the answer. (Will delete this comment after Answer is created)